# tricky report in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, report

I am computing statistics on item distribution in a game, every months.

I have a table like this:

```
Date   itemname  quantity avg. price
Mar-2012 x         10       3.45
Mar-2012 y         12       4.66
Apr-2012 x         23       4.56
Apr-2012 y         9        4.6
```

How in PHP i can build an array and construct a table that show the following report for the last 6 months?

```
    Mar-2012            Apr-2012
quantity avg_price  quantity avg_price

x   10        3.45        23     4.56
y   12        4.66        9      4.6
```

I am not able to create such a report. any help?

Thanks

---

Found solution; I wanted to know if there was an easy way in PHP to do it. I understood i had to apply some logic. Solution follow (kohana 2.x code):

Controller:

```
$db = Database::instance();
$months = $db -> query( "select distinct from_unixtime( timestamp, '%m-%Y') month
from stats_items 
where timestamp >= ( unix_timestamp() - ( 6 * 30 * 24 * 3600 ) ) order by timestamp asc" ) -> as_array();               

$res = ORM::factory('stats_item') -> find_all();
foreach ( $res as $r )
{
  $stats[$r->name][date('M-Y', $r -> timestamp)]['total'] = $r -> total;
  $db = Database::instance();
  $months = $db -> query( "select distinct from_unixtime( timestamp, '%m-%Y') month
  from stats_items where timestamp >= ( unix_timestamp() - ( 6 * 30 * 24 * 3600 ) ) order by timestamp asc" ) -> as_array();                

  $res = ORM::factory('stats_item') -> find_all();

  foreach ( $res as $r )
 {
        $stats[$r->name][date('M-Y', $r -> timestamp)]['total'] = $r -> total;
        $stats[$r->name][date('M-Y', $r -> timestamp)]['avg_price'] = $r -> avg_price;
    }

    $view->months = $months;
    $view->stats_items = $stats;stats[$r->name][date('M-Y', $r -> timestamp)]['avg_price'] = $r -> avg_price;
    }

    $view->months = $months;
    $view->stats_items = $stats;
```

View:

```
<table>
<?php

echo "<tr><td width='20%'></td>";
foreach ( $months as $month )   
echo "<td colspan='2' style='text-align:center' width='20%'>" . $month -> month .    '</td>' ; 
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Item</td>';
foreach ( $months as $month )   
    echo "<td>Total</td><td>Avg Price</td>";
echo '</tr>';

$i=0;
foreach ( $stats_items as $key => $value )
{   
$class = ( $i % 2 == 0 ) ? 'alternaterow' : '' ; 
echo "<tr class='$class'>";
echo '<td>'. kohana::lang( $key) . '</td>' ;


foreach ( $value as $key2 => $value2 )  
{   
    echo "<td class='tright'>".$value2['total'].'</td>'; 
    echo "<td class='tright'>".$value2['avg_price'].'</td>'; 
}
echo '</tr>';
$i++;

}
?>
```

Comment: If you have this in an array, are you able to identify which rows occur in the last six months? That's the first step. Then, add your quantities together, and add your prices together, and divide by the number of rows. (Give this a go, and then paste your code here - we'll give you some pointers).

Comment: Well, this requires a bit of logic. I guess it would be easy to recompute the data in a multidimentional array(). Where exactly are you struggling?

Comment: Hi ladiesMan217, how can i accept a question? i don't see any button to accept a question...

Comment: The same way you've accepted answers to the other half you've done, click the checkmark by the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, I found the way to do it  after i answered you; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = preg_match_all('/(.*?)[ ]+(.*?)[ ]+(.*?)[ ]+(.*)/',$subject,PREG_SET_ORDER);
$grouped = array();
foreach($result as $res){
  $grouped[$res[1]][] = arrary($res[2],$res[3],$res[4]);
}
$width = 18;

foreach($grouped as $key => $group){
  $len = strlen($key);
  echo str_repeat(' ',floor(($width- $len)/2)) . $key .  str_repeat(' ',ceil(($width- $len)/2)) ;
}
foreach($grouped as $key => $group){
 echo 'quantity avg_price  ';
}
for($i =0;$i < 100;$i++){
  foreach($grouped as $key => $group){
    echo $group[$i][0] .  $group[$i][1] .  $group[$i][2] ;
  }
}
```

Something like this (untested)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd make a class `Item` and cast each item and all of its appropriate data into it, then make object methods to handle all of the calculations.

Then make the data table in HTML based on the data collected.